# Is there a way to show Skeleton whenever I click on pagination buttons and then disable it after 3 seconds?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, material-ui

This part of my code shows a `Skeleton` which is a placeholder preview for `CardMedia`.

```
{loading ? (
  <Skeleton
    variant="rectangular"
    width={308}
    height={420}
    animation="wave"
  />
) : (
  <CardMedia
    sx={{ height: 420 }}
    image={item.itemMainPic}
    title="green iguana"
  />
)}
```

I'm showing the `Skeleton` when the `loading` is `true` and using `useEffect` after 3 seconds I `setLoading(false)`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    setLoading(false);
  }, 3000);
}, []);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
```

I have other `CardMedia`s that I can show them using the pagination:

```
const handleChange = (event, value) => {
  setCurrentpage(value);
};

<Pagination
  count={Math.ceil(Myjson.length / postsPerpage)}
  onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

But when I click on different pagination buttons, it no longer shows a `Skeleton`, so that means I have to reload  the window, in other words the `useEffect` works only once and when I load other cards using pagination there is no `Skeleton`.

Is there a way to show `Skeleton` whenever I click on pagination buttons and then disable it after 3 seconds?

Since the code was too long, I simplified it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you are basically wanting to render the skeleton on the initial component mount ***and*** any time the `currentPage` state updates. For this I believe you can add `currentPage` as a dependency to the `useEffect` hook.

Example:

```
const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = React.useState(....);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
  setLoading(true);

  const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    setLoading(false);
  }, 3000);

  // Return cleanup function to clear timer if currentPage updates
  // or the component unmounts prior to timeout expiring.
  return () => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  };
}, [currentPage]);

...
```

With the above logic there's a chance that the UI will update and momentarily render the next page because the `currentPage` state updates and the component rerenders *just* prior to the next `useEffect` call that triggers conditionally rendering the skeleton. If this is an issue and you want to avoid it then another solution would be to enqueue setting the `loading` state at the same time as enqueueing the `currentPage` state update. This is so they are updated at the same time during the same render.

Example:

```
const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = React.useState(....);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

const timerRef = React.useRef();

const triggerSkeleton = () => {
  setLoading(true);

  // Clear any previously running timeout
  clearTimeout(timerRef.current);

  // Set new timeout
  timerRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
    setLoading(false);
  }, 3000);
};

useEffect(() => {
  // Trigger the skeleton and timer on initial component mount
  triggerSkeleton();

  // Return cleanup function to clear timer if
  // the component unmounts prior to timeout expiring.
  return () => {
    clearTimeout(timerRef.current);
  };
}, []);

const handleChange = (event, value) => {
  setCurrentpage(value);
  triggerSkeleton();
};

...
```

Comment: After using your code, when `currentPage` state updates, for a short time I see the cards, and then `Skeleton` begins to work; I don't know why that happens.

Comment: @daan Ok, I think I see what a possible effect is with that first implementation. I've updated the answer to include an implementation that updates `currentPage` and `loading` state ***at-the-same*** time.